# css wrapper is not taking 100% height of whole page

Tags: html, css, css-position

Well I thought that would be an easy thing and I'll do it in five minutes, but it took me now hours, so I hope you can help me with this silly and often asked question.

I'm trying to set the height of my wrapping div to 100%. Inside the wrapper, I have a `header, content and footer` which all have some height. I also have a div called "slider" inside my content div, which should stick on the contents top.

My problem is that the wrapping div only takes the height of my browser window instead of the whole page.

To fit the slider div to top of the content div, I set `position:relative;` to content div and `position:absolute;` to slider div. And there appears my second problem. The absolute sliding div is overlapping the rest of the content, because the rest of the content jumps to the top because of the absolute positioning of slider div.

My wrapper div styling looks like this:

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:green;
}
```

And the content and slider div looks like this:

```
#slider{
    /* random image from google */
    background:url('http://makuwi.ch/wahl_informatik/download/carla_m/handball7.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:45%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

#container{
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
    background:orange;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

I prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq5zrcos/1/) with the relevant code to demonstrate you my problem.

Collectively, I have 2 problems:

1. The wrapper div does not take the 100% height of the page
2. The slider div overlappes the rest of my content

As I said before I first thought I'd fix this in a few minutes but now I'm here asking this question because I'm not able to fix it.

Suggestions appreciated :)

**EDIT:** Since I have two questions in 1 SO question, I got two different answers.

The solution for my first problem is this one: [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32978655/2060526) 
The solution for my second problem is this one: [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32979000/2060526)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wq5zrcos/4/ what you want?

Comment: Mh not exactly. It should scroll the whole page, not only the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `min-height` for `html, body`. In your case:

```
html,
body
{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background:purple;
}
```

Comment: Well now I'm very confused. If I change it in my jsFiddle it works fine. But if I copy the whole fiddle in a new file on my local computer, the wrapper doesn't fit...

Comment: Show the file. Paste on pastebin all

Comment: well, on my Chrome it looks as on pastebin :/

Comment: Okay it was a caching problem. I cleared the cache & the cookies and now it looks good. Thank you!

Comment: If I'm using the code in this jsFiddle, my header is not taking the height anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/wq5zrcos/7/ Can you please explain me this behaviour?

Comment: I dont know why you are using percent values, :( I think that `px` would resolve a lot of problems.

Comment: Because on smaller or bigger screens it will calculate the pixel itself. With fixed pixel it will always have the same height...

Comment: I am over 2 years in the industry and from my experience using `%` isnt never good solution (excepts specific intetional). Please consider using for example `@media-queries`

Comment: Hmm okay. So you mean catch the monitor size and change the style for different screen sizes?

Comment: Exactly. Then you will have full control over page behavior.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the body and the html tags have some strange paddings, so you need to add `html, body {padding: 0;}` to your CSS code.

About the slider;
Because the slider has a position absolute, all the other content will ignore the slider div, but the slider ignores all other content too, except a parent div with a position relative. But, we need to add a padding top to the content div, so all the content except the elements with a position absolute. `#container {padding-top: 45%;}`

The height of the content has to be set on auto. So it will take the height that is needed to position the child elements. So add `#wrapper {height:auto;}`

Your code should be:

CSS

```
html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
}

body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:purple;
}

#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    background:green;
}

header{
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    background:darkblue;
    position:relative;
}

#slider{
    background:url('http://makuwi.ch/wahl_informatik/download/carla_m/handball7.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:45%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

#container{
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
    background:orange;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding-top: 45%;
}

footer{
    width:50%;
    height:5%;
    background:purple;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="logodiv"></div>
    </header>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="slider"></div>

        <div id="randomtext">
            <p>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
                aaa<br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div id="linkssponsoren">
            <p>Links/Sponsoren</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay, this fixed the problem with the overlapping slider. But the problem with the wrapper height still exists. Anyway, thanks for solving one of those two problems

Comment: Thanks, but auto height didn't work for me. I made a mix from your answer and the answer of Rafal. This is my fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/wq5zrcos/7/ But the header has no height anymore... Why is `height:25%;` for header not working anymore?

Comment: Because you can't set a height in percentage to an element if the parent div has the height auto. So you have to use px instead of %.

Comment: Well but no parent has `height:auto;`?

Answer (score 0):

the wrapper should be in absolute:position and try to specify the display